# Get json and sort with multiple arguments

Tags: php, json

Well, my question are complicated.

I have that json file:

```
{
"books": [
    {
        "book": [
            {
                "Title": "Java How to Program",
                "Author": "Deitel & Deitel",
                "Edition": "2007"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "book": [
            {
                "Title": "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture",
                "Author": "Martin Fowler",
                "Edition": "2002"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "book": [
            {
                "Title": "Head First Design Patterns",
                "Author": "Elisabeth Freeman",
                "Edition": "2004"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "book": [
            {
                "Title": "Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program",
                "Author": "Deitel & Deitel",
                "Edition": "2007"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

In my PHP i have this:

```
    $file = file_get_contents('books.json');
    $json = json_decode($file, true);
```

How can i sort my array by multiples rules? For example:

```
echo sort_my_array('Title', ASC, 'Author', DESC, $json);
```

I've tried in so many ways but i think my error is at when i try to use the array_multidimensional.

Can someone explain to me how to create this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This JSON is badly structured, which makes your data be unnecessarily nested (`print_r($json)` to see what happens). You can fix this from PHP of course, but it would perhaps be better to make the JSON a little more sane.

Comment: PHP fix: before sorting, `$json = array_map(function($a) { return $a['book'][0]; }, $json['books']);`

Comment: Thanks @Jon, your fix works fine. I totally sucks at json files and arrays. Now i stuck at sorting :(

Comment: The problem is that this data makes itself very hard to sort (and to use in general). I don't know who consumes this JSON, but if you control both producer and consumer just fix the producer instead of patching the consumer.

Comment: shit job test... it's killing me. Need to create a sorting service of these 4 books SORTING they via PHP but i can't use any DataBase. I've think that json will be the solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
    $file = file_get_contents('books.json');
    $json = json_decode($file, true);
   $json = array_map(function($a) { return $a['book'][0]; }, $json['books']);
 foreach ($json as $key => $row) {
    $title[$key] = $row['Title'];
   $author[$key] = $row['Author'];
 }
 array_multisort($title, SORT_ASC,  $author, SORT_DESC, $json);
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($json);
 echo "</pre>";
```

I have tried it and its working

Comment: Wow man... thanks for that awnser. It's exactly what i'm need. Thanks again!

Comment: We are here to help each other ..happy Coding ...

Comment: @Alexandre & new_developer +1 to both of you guys for the sportsmanship & appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

use `array_multisort`

```
<?php
$json = '{
"books": [
{
    "book": [
        {
            "Title": "Java How to Program",
            "Author": "Deitel & Deitel",
            "Edition": "2007"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "book": [
        {
            "Title": "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture",
            "Author": "Martin Fowler",
            "Edition": "2002"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "book": [
        {
            "Title": "Head First Design Patterns",
            "Author": "Elisabeth Freeman",
            "Edition": "2004"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "book": [
        {
            "Title": "Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program",
            "Author": "Deitel & Deitel",
            "Edition": "2007"
        }
    ]
}
]
}';

$json = json_decode($json,true);
echo "<pre>";
//print_r($json);

$sort = array();
foreach($json['books'] as $k=>$v) {
$sort['title'][$k] = $v['book'][0]['Title'];
$sort['author'][$k] = $v['book'][0]['Author'];
}
//print_r($sort);
array_multisort($sort['title'], SORT_DESC, $sort['author'], SORT_ASC,$json['books']);
print_r($json['books']);
```

output http://codepad.viper-7.com/dXjDLg

Comment: Hey'a... i've got some errors while setting your code... take a look: http://i.imgur.com/GyiFlF0.jpg

Comment: @Alexandre fixed the issue. Now see the working example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)  — Sort multiple or multi-dimensional arrays.

**example:**

```
<?php
// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($book as $key => $row) {
    $Title[$key]  = $row['Title'];
    $Author[$key] = $row['Author'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($Title, SORT_ASC, $Author, SORT_DESC, $book);
?>
```

may this help you.

Comment: In that case, my array will be divided no? Sorry, i don't understand much about arrays. I need the multiple rules works in same array. Like in SQL: `mysql .... ORDER BY Title ASC, Edition DESC` is that what your code do? If yes... what about "obtain a list of columns"? Sorry i really don't get that part. English are not my first language so it's a bit hard to understand some parts, sorry.